# Refresh datepicker onced saved to database via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
        from = $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            minDate: 0,
        }).on( "change", function() {
            to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
        to = $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            minDate: 0,
        }).on("change", function() {
            from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
        });

    function getDate(element) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }
        return date;
    }
});
```

I am working with `jquery datepicker`. Firstly I am picking a start and an end date. Then I am sending the dates using `ajax` to save it to the database.

I am clearing the input date field like this:

`document.getElementById('from').value = '';`

`document.getElementById('to').value = '';`

After that, once I want to add another date it will make the `datepicker` (dates based on the selected start date and end date) `disabled` .

I just want to refresh the `datepicker` to enable me to freely choose and add another date.

Comment: I already resolve my own issue. Thank you for the 2 of you.

Comment: If below answer don't address your problem post your own answer and accept that as a working answer. That's how SO work.

Comment: $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", null );                                            
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", 0);                                                                                                                          This resolve my problem. I don't know the main reason on how the logic of this code.. But it resolve my problem in refreshing the select a date range.

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize your date picker in `Ajax success` like below.

```
success: function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker();
            $( "#to" ).datepicker();
        } ,
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear textbox you can use `$("#textboxid").val('');`. And according to your requirement you need to put below code in ajax success block to reinitialize the datepicker.

```
$("#dpFrom").val('');
$("#dpTo").val('');
$("#dpFrom").datepicker();
$("#dpTo").datepicker();
```

In the below code snippet you can see the clearing of datepicker textboxes and re initializing the datepicker.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#dpFrom").datepicker();
    $("#dpTo").datepicker();
});

function clearDates() {
    $("#dpFrom").val('');
    $("#dpTo").val('');
    $("#dpFrom").datepicker();
    $("#dpTo").datepicker();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label>From Date: </label>
<input type="text" id="dpFrom">
<br />
<label>To Date: </label>
<input type="text" id="dpTo">
<br />
<button onclick="clearDates();">Clear and Reinitialize Datepicker</button>
```